# Tell How Function was called

Tags: php, debugging, function, backtrace

I've looked at debug_backtrace but so far it doesn't do what I need it to do.

I need to know whether the function I'm calling was 'called' or 'echo-ed'.  Like this:

```
function hello() {
    //blah blah
}

echo hello(); //echo-ed
hello(); //'called'
```

But the function would do different things if it was 'called' over 'echo-ed'.

How would I do that?

Comment: Not sure this can be done at all, because `echo` is not a function. Can you show the different backtraces?... But if you are looking to build a function that detects whether it's being echoed, I would stop right away. Backtraces are expensive - this should be solved differently

Comment: You should accept an answer to some of your questions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is impossible. The reason this cannot work is that "echo" or any other operator, function or variable assignment uses **the return value** of the function you've called. So if you've got the following:

```
echo function1();
```

What happens is that function1 gets executed, and the return value is passed to echo. Therefor, function1 cannot possibly know that its return value is going to be "echo-ed", because by the time that happens, function1() has already been called and finished executing.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure it's not only impossible, but also against all common sense. A function should not know or care about the context in which it's been called. All the function needs to care about is it's arguments, and it's inner scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is no efficient way to deal it

**Update:**
There is *no* way to deal it :)

Comment: If you don't have an answer, then don't post one.

Comment: This IS the answer?! It's not possible.

Comment: A bit short on words, but fair enough :) +1

Comment: Well, actually the answer IS wrong, because it says that there is no "efficient" way, however there is none, efficient or otherwise.

Comment: To make it a good answer you should provide a prove and not just a statement ;-)

Answer (score 0):

two examples to help you understand.

```
function hello(){
  return "Hello!";
}
echo hello(); // prints Hello!


function hello(){
  echo "Hello!";
}
hello(); // prints Hello!
```